# Treeview doesn't contain records when refresh the page in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo, postgresql-9.1

I added a tree view to a page of my `notebook` element. While adding data to the tree view it is saving in the database, and it is also displayed in the tree view. When I reload the page, the data in the tree view vanishes and it's empty.

The code looks like this:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <notebook colspan="4">
        <page string="Block Area">
            <field colspan="4" name="block_line" nolabel="1" mode="tree,form">
                <tree string="Block">
                    <field name="blockname" />
                    <field name="size" />
                    <field name="activefrom" />
                    <field name="activethru" />
                    <field name="active" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </page>
    </notebook>
</field>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Santu. Please add some more details to help others answer your question. After you reload the page, do you still see the data in the database? Did you click the Save button before you clicked the Reload button? Does your screen behave any differently from the order lines on the Sales Order screen?

Answer (score 1):

As Don Kirkby said, first, you must check all the conditions which he asked.

moreover, as per my point of view, there is one2many field "block_line" in your treeview,
for this field you should check below conditions.

**In py :**

this field should have referenced to many2one field (you can call block_id) in your one2many class.

**In XML :**

M2O (block_id) field should be there in O2M tree and form view (visible/invisible)

**Save Record :**

appropriate form id (current record id) must be stored in M2O field, when saving the O2M line record.

If it wouldn't be store on save action, then record will be there in database for one2many class but will not be visible in your tree view. as there is no M2O reference id stored (or may be wrong M2O id stored) in O2M class to show the related O2M records.

In your case, if data in the database but not displayed in tree view, then above is the case you need to check for.

NOTE : take reference of sale.order and sale.order.line class for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have not written any search filter conditions for the model of the field 'block_line'. Since you have added the active field in block_line only the active records will be shown. So you have to check the field active or have to provide some data.